# Find maximum number of equal subsets of size 3 using each index only once.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, approximation-theory

Specifically, An array of numbers is being given(duplication allowed) and we have to find maximum numbers of subset(subset need not to be contiguous) each having size of 3 such that sum of each subset is equal. Values in array can be negative, zero or positive. 
My approach so far is to run a loop for each value of sum and find out subsets of size 3 and finally report the maximum number of subset. Surely this is exponential time algorithm. I am looking for better randomized, approximate alogrithm.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n$ be the size of the original array $S$.

**Step 1**. You need to calculate all possible sums of all triples - you'll get a three-dimensional array $A$ of sums. It'll take $O(n^3)$ operations. Actually, you'll need only approximately $\frac{1}{6}$ of this array, because each triple must have *distinct* elements from the $S$.

**Step 2**. You need to sort this array of sums, remembering also all the corresponding triples. It'll take $O(n^3log(n))$ operations. The sorting will allow you to partition the array $A$ into sets of triples with the same sum.

**Step 3**. For each set of triples with the same sum you need to solve an integer programming (IP) sub-problem, which can be approximated by a linear programming (LP) sub-problem. You have elements from the original set $S$ and triples with these elements. You need to find a largest subset of triples, satisfying the condition: each element from $S$ can participate in not more than one triple from this subset. Let's denote this condition (***).

Let $x_k \in \{0, 1\}$ be an integer variable, equal to $1$ if and only if the triple with index $k$ is included into the *maximal* set of triples. Then the IP criteria will be:

$$maximize(x_0 + x_1 + ... + x_{m-1})$$

where $m$ - the number of triples in the given set of triples.

In order to build constraints for the IP sub-problem you need to construct an incidence matrix $B$ between elements from $S$ and triples. The matrix $B$ will have $n$ rows and $m$ columns. Let the $b_{i,k}$ - element of the matrix $B$. The $b_{i,k} = 1$ if and only if the element from $S$ with index $i$ is a member of the triple with index $k$. The condition (***) for an element with index $i$ can be expressed in a following way:

$$b_{i,0}\cdot x_0 + b_{i,1} \cdot x_1 + ... + b_{i,m-1} \cdot x_{m-1} \le 1$$

It's well known that the IP problem is NP-hard. However, you can redefine variables $x_k$ as real-valued ones: $x_k \in [0, 1]$ and get an *LP approximation* for the original IP sub-problem. The LP sub-problem can be solved in polynomial time, then you'll be able to round variables $x_k$ and get integer-valued solution.

(However, I don't have any estimate for now, how good that approximation will be.)